# Return a generic list from a generic function

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have an interface which is generic.

```
public interface IModel<T> 
{
   List<T> ReadModelInfo();
   .....
}
```

Now I have 2 specific classes which implements that interface `IModel<T>`.

```
Class IceModel<T> : IModel<T>
{
        List<T>ReadModelInfo<T>()
        {
           List<Product> pdList = GetList() 
           return pdList as List<T>();
        }
}
```

The method `ReadModelInfo()` throws an error:

> as Invalid expression term ')' :expected and ) expected.

Does anyone have any idea how to return a generic list from a specific list?

Comment: Why is it generic if it only supports one type? This won't compile until you remove the generic parameter from `ReadModelInfo`.

Comment: Does your method signature really has no space between the name and the type?

Comment: The generic method in the class does not implement the non-generic method declared in the interface.

Comment: Does `IceModel` really need to be generic or should it be declared as `class IceModel : IModel<Product>`?

Comment: Please provide more information about your class heirarchy - we can give a better answer then.  Does Product have base class?  Do other implementations of the interface use a different class that Product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the simple answer is:

```
return pdList.Cast<T>().toList()
```

But obviously this will only work if T is Product or a superclass of Product, so this suggests that maybe there is a problem with your design.

Comment: This looks like a case of using Generics for the sake of it, rather than implementing a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an incorrect usage of generic types.

```
class IceModel<T> : IModel<T>
```

Should be able to be substituted with

```
class IceModel : IModel<Product>
```

That would give a more natural implementation of the interface (which seems to be what you are trying to do anyway?)

```
class IceModel : IModel<Product>
{
   List<Product> ReadModelInfo()
    {
       List<Product> pdList = GetList() 
       return pdList;
    }
}
```

Comment: The main requirement is to get generic List<T> from specific list like for example  RubberProduct list in code below. Basically I want to know how to cook generic list out of specific list.

Comment: class ICEModel<T> : IMOdel<T>
{
    List<PlasticProduct> pdList = new List<PlasticProduct>();
   
    List<T>ReadModelInfo()
       {
  
  // Reading plastic model information 
  return pdList;
       }

 void ProcessItems( List<T> faultyItems )
 {
    //Do some processing
 }
}


class SugarModel<T> : IMOdel<T>
{
    List<RubberProduct> pdList = new List<RubberProduct>();
   
    List<T>ReadModelInfo()
       {
   //Reading  rubber model info. 
     return pdList;
       }

       void ProcessItems( List<T> faultyItems )
 {
    //Do some processing
 }
}